# How to read a section from appsettings.json using .Net core console application?

Tags: c#, json

I have a appsettings.json file as below

```
{
  "student":{
     "subject": "0;3",
     "grade": "4;5"
   }
}
```

I want to read the section student and add it to a dictionary. My dictionary keys will be subject and grade. For that I am doing the following to get the section student.  I don't want to define any class to store the section student.

```
            var config = new Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder()
             .SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.Location))
                .AddJsonFile("appsetting.json").Build();
        var result= config.GetSection("student");
```

But values are not getting populated in result.

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the reason for not wanting to define a data structure for your configuration? That generally helps simplify any code you're writing. Regardless of that, are you sure that the config file exists at the path that you are adding it from? Can you inspect the value of config to see if the student path exists?

Comment: Why would they be? That's the section, not the data in the section. Did you check to see what members are available on `result` and what those members do?

Answer (score 2):

you should create a separate object that contains the values. check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0)